# Progress bar based on video download

Tags: javascript, html, video, download, progress-bar

Below is a piece of code from an electron desktop app I'm working on that downloads videos using youtube-dl.

How would I display a progress bar based on the progress point of the video download? Below is my attempt, but I have not been able to get the progress bar to update along with the video.

HTML:

```
<body>
  <form id="target">
      <input type="text" id="video_url" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
  <progress id="myBar" value="0" max="100"></progress>
  <span id="status"></span>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
"use strict";
var fs = require('fs');
var youtubedl = require('youtube-dl');

document.querySelector("#target").addEventListener("submit",function(e) {

  var url = document.getElementById("video_url").value;

  var video = youtubedl(url);

  let size = 0;
  let pos = 0;
  let progress = 0;
  var bar = document.getElementById('myBar');
  var barValue = bar.value;

  video.on('info', function(info) {
    size = info.size;
  });

  video.on('data', (chunk) => {
    pos += chunk.length;
    if (size) {
      progress = (pos / size * 100).toFixed(2);
      barValue++;
    };
  });

  video.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('video.mp4'));

  e.preventDefault();

});
```